# Promise inside a for loop not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a simple code wrapping create method with a promise as:

```
function create(api, record) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        api.create(record, function (err, result) {
             if (err) reject(err);
             else resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

I want to use to insert records into my database as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dummyData.products.length; i++) {
  create(productsAPIService, dummyData.products[i])
    .then(function(product) {
      logInsert("product", false, product._id);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      logInsert("product", err, product._id);
    });
}
```

For unclear to me reason, this thing inserts only first record, it seems. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What about the logs which you inserted? Are they also getting written only once?

Comment: `return` the promise from the `then`, promises work by return value.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L81ffcke/1/ seems to work as expected here.

Comment: @BeNdErR - you are must be right. at least, i figured out where the problem is. it is elsewhere. thank you

Comment: @BeNdErR It's worth noting that you should look into `[].map()` and `Promise.all()`.